# With Scala's Set, is there a method analog to the containsAll method in Java's Set?

Tags: java, scala, set, contains

While working through converting some Java code over to Scala, I discovered while there is a `contains` method for Scala's `Set`, there isn't a `containsAll` method. Am I just missing the correct method name?

Here's a bit of code I worked up to fill in the gap so I could quickly get back to working. Is it sufficient, or am I missing some subtlety?

```
  def containsAll[A](set: Set[A], subset: Set[A]): Boolean =
    if (set.size >= subset.size)
      subset.forall(a => set.contains(a))
    else
      false
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is `subsetOf`, which tests whether or not the elements of a `Set` are contained within another `Set`. (Kind of the reverse in terms of the expression)

```
val set = Set(1,2,3,4)
val subset = Set(1,2)

scala> subset.subsetOf(set)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> set.subsetOf(subset)
res1: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Ah. Very nice. It's a bit counterintutive in that it is reversed from Java. But it certainly does what I need. Tysvm for your rapid response.

Answer (score 8):

In Scala, `Set` is equipped with set operations such as `intersect`, thus for instance

```
set.intersect(subset) == subset
```

conveys the semantics of `containsAll`, even that `subsetOf` as already mentioned proves the most succinct.

Comment: Isn't this substantially less performant on sets of very large size (imagine millions of entries)? IOW, now there are two operations, performing the intersection and then performing the equivalence check. It seems a single pass through the first set testing for elements within the second set would be far preferable and far more performant.

Answer (score 7):

It's worth adding that you can make derived helper methods like `containsAll` available on `Set[T]` if you want, by using an implicit enriched class.  You might also consider making a variadic overload:

```
implicit class RichSet[T](val x: Set[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def containsAll(y: Set[T]): Boolean = y.subsetOf(x)
    def containsAll(y: T*): Boolean = x.containsAll(y.toSet)
}
```

So then you can do:

```
Set(1, 2, 3).containsAll(Set(1, 2))
```

Or:

```
Set(1, 2, 3).containsAll(1, 2)
```

Comment: Very nicely done! I will be definitely adding this to my library.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind explicitly using 'extends AnyVal' as opposed to leaving that implied?

Comment: It is more efficient.  From the docs: "...it is possible to define a subclass of AnyVal called a user-defined value class which is treated specially by the compiler. Properly-defined user value classes provide a way to improve performance on user-defined types by avoiding object allocation at runtime, and by replacing virtual method invocations with static method invocations." Read more about `AnyVal` and user-defined value classes here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.AnyVal

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers are all good, I'm just throwing-in another option. This one would also work with `List`s which don't have `subsetOf` method:

```
Set(1,2,3) forall(Set(3, 2, 1) contains)
```

Comment: Beware of duplicates when working with List.